# what is the force required to seat a staple?

Tags: forces, energy, momentum

i understand the staple needs to overcome the friction force and also push material out to completely seat. how would i go about finding the force required to seat a particular guage thickness? There are formulas out there for withdrawal force, but i think the push force would be higher.

Comment: Probably also a function of amount of pages and page thickness; along with gauge of the staple and peg length.

Comment: the staples i am using will go into wood. I am just not sure what equations are involved in calculating the force to pierce the wood

Comment: Why not measure it?

Comment: Sammy, how would you measure the force of a staple going into wood?

Answer (score 3):

At least three main forces are relevant to the seating of a staple (also see figure below):

- The force required for the leading points of the staple to make a
  hole in each layer of paper.
- The force required to overcome friction on the sides of the staple as it slices through successive layers of paper.
- The force required to bend the staple as it exits the successive layers of paper, contacts the smooth (stainless steel) guiding grooves at the bottom, and bends inwards.

To pierce the paper requires that the force per unit area $F/A$ at the staple leading point, be in excess of the shear strength $\tau$ of the paper, or $F > \tau A$.

As the staple enters the paper stack, the friction coefficient between the staple and the paper, multiplied by the force exerted on the staple trunk sides by the paper it has pierced, gives you the force required to push the stapler down the pile of papers against friction:

$F_{friction} = \mu N_{sideways}$

As the staple exits the paper stack at the bottom, contacting the groove, with a friction coefficient $\mu$ between the stapler and groove surface, the vertical force $F$ must be enough to result in enough stress to cause the outer surface of the staple just exiting the paper, stack to yield in bending. The equation for this stress is:

$\sigma_x = {{My}\over I_x},\qquad$ where M is the bending moment applied, y is the perpendicular distance from the neutral axis, and $I_x$ is the second moment of area about the neutral axis x. of the staple's trunk. The bending moment is $Ftan\theta$, where $F$ is the vertical force applied. To overcome friction between the staple point and the groove, we must add $\mu F$, giving a total requirement

$F(tan\theta + \mu) > \sigma_x$.

After the staple tip exits the bottom of the stack, apart from the initial piercing force, the forces act concurrently.

[image: seating of staple]

Comment: Question is about wood staples according to the comments.

Comment: so if the staple were just going into wood, then  i can ignore the bending moment portion. How does the cross section of the staple legs (2 rectangles) affect the force required to seat the staple?

Comment: @JMac Thank you for pointing that out. The approach is mainly unchanged whether paper or wood. One can ignore the final bending for wood, since it is not required.

Comment: @javandjim Yes, we can ignore the bending moment part for wood. About the cross section of the staples: if the staples have a larger cross-sectional area (generally means thicker), which means they will be stronger in tension, i.e. they will make it harder to pull the wood apart once stapled. However, since the area $A$ is larger, you need to apply a larger force $F$ to pierce the surface of the wood in order to exceed its shear strength $\tau$.